# Is there any online personal finance software without online banking?

Tags: software, online-tools

I realize that similar questions have been raised, especially regarding Mint and Quicken Online, but my question is this:  Is there web-based personal finance software that does not require you to register an online bank account within the software?

I really want the ability to do personal finance online, without having to reveal any personal or bank information at all to the service. I'm pretty sure Quicken and Mint require an online institution "so they can make things convenient for you," but I don't trust **anybody** that much.

Comment: If you don't want to reveal any personal information, why bother with online at all?  Just keep it local...

Comment: @sdg : I don't mind providing personal information like my email (for user/pass management), but that is very different than providing personal information like my banking institution and associated credentials for getting statements, etc.

Comment: sure, but you are still storing personal financial details "in the cloud".  I was just confirming that is really what you wanted.

Comment: @sdg : My anonymous personal budget online is fine. This would NOT include my bank account numbers or banking credentials.

Answer (score 5):

[CashBase](http://www.cashbasehq.com) has a web app, an iPhone app and an Android app, all sync'ed up. It doesn't integrate with banks automatically, but you can import bank statements as CSV.

*Disclosure: Filip is CashBase's founder.*

Comment: unfortunately CashBase does not intrinsicly support : Payment Types, sub categories, or check numbers.

Comment: @AshMachine, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @pacecier : I mean that CashBase does not support entering things like check numbers, sub-cats (Like travel as a sub cat of Entertainment) nor payment types (like e-checks, checks, deposits, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

[neobudget.com](http://neobudget.com) is a website that does exactly what you are describing. It is set up for electronically using the envelope system of budgeting.

Disclosure: neobudget was founded by a former coworker of mine.

Answer (score 2):

[MoneyStrands](https://money.strands.com/) is a site very similar to Mint, but does not force you to link bank accounts. You can create manual accounts and use all features of the site without linking to banks.

Answer (score 2):

**[SavingsMap](http://www.SavingsMap.com)** is a web-based personal finance forecasting tool that requires no bank account or personal information other than an email address.

As founder of SavingsMap, our goal is to forecast future cash flows based on your current budget, while using strategies to minimize US tax obligations and taking into account expected major life events.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Xero Personal does. I have my bank account in there, but since there's no automatic feed for the bank I use I imported it manually. I entered the bank by hand, so I think you could use it without listing a bank account at all.

Comment: Xero indeed doesn't require one, but offers a neat importing facility. Recommended to check out.

Comment: and silver This is helpful, but $19/month is spendy.  I found HomeBank (free) while searching around, and I think I will give that a try.  You can import bank statements without setting up a bank in the application.

Comment: After trying I cannot recommend HomeBank, the export as CSV is not correct and the money is represented not as decimal, but as floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @AshMachine: I know this is an old thread, but Xero Personal is $34/year rather than $19/month.

Answer (score 1):

[PocketSmith](http://www.pocketsmith.com/) is another tool you might like to consider. No personal banking details are required, but you can upload your transactions in a variety of formats.

Pocketsmith is interesting because it really focus on your future cash flow, and the main feature of the interface is around having a calendar(s) where you easily enter one off or repetitive expenses/income. http://www.pocketsmith.com/

Answer (score 0):

Out Of The Dark OOTD is a budgeting and personal money management web app that does not require you to give out access to your bank accounts or even your personal identity.  It's a great tool for people with no financial experience with features like Cash Put-Aside and the Credit Card Debt Terminator and it has tons of instant guides explaining how to use every feature.  You can check it out at myootd.org.

Comment: It appears you promote this tool widely on other web sites as well.  Are you affiliated with the company/product in question?  Stack Exchange requires you to disclose any affiliation in your answer.  See http://money.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion.